# Why do my coordinates (pageX/pageY) change at end of drag?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement an HTML5 draggable, but I'm seeing something which doesn't make a lot of sense.  I have a React component like so:

```
class Draggable extends React.Component {
    _onDragEnd(e) {
        console.log(`end`, e.pageX)
    }
    _onDrag(e) {
        console.log(`drag`, e.pageX)
    }
    _onDragStart(e) {
        console.log(`start`, e.pageX)
    }
    return <div draggable={true}
                onDrag={this._onDrag.bind(this)}
                onDragEnd={this._onDragEnd.bind(this)}
                onDragStart={this._onDragStart.bind(this)}
    }
}
```

When I drag it I see the following output:

```
start 276
drag 279
drag 280
drag 281
drag 282
drag 283
drag 285
drag 286
drag 287
drag 288
drag 289
end 2209
```

Notice that the `pageX` at the end of the drag is almost 2k bigger than the `pageX` from the `drag` event that happened just before it.  Since I know I'm not moving my mouse 2k in between the last `drag` event and the `dragEnd` event, I'm baffled as to why the `dragEnd` `pageX` is so much bigger.

Has anyone who has used the HTML 5 drag and drop seen anything like this before, and if so do you know how to fix it?  I realize that I could just work around the problem by saving the `pageX` in my `_onDrag` handler, but I'm curious to understand why the `dragEnd` event's `pageX` is so different.

**EDIT:** I just tried using `clientX` and `screenX` instead of `pageX`.   `clientX` has the same strange jump at the end of the drag, but for some reason the `screenX` at the end matches the `screenX` from the last drag.  However, I don't *think* I want to use `screenX`, because as I understand it if I use `screenX` and the user drags enough to make the page scroll the `screenX` will be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the question is already so old, but maybe I can still help one or the other. The coordinates are apparently determined via the draggable element.

Probably `ghostElement.getBoundingClientRect()`.

In Chrome clientY jumps to 0 onDrag, in Safari it behaves a bit different. Funny white it is in Chrome on onDragEnd again correct, but in Safari the error on onDrag is not present, but onDrag is wrong.

I was actually using this on top of the react onDrag handler as a guard:

```js
 if (event.clientY === 0) return
```

After dragging I calculate the information based on my learnings of onDrag, as safari will have problems here.